# How to Start Toggle navigation bar from 1024px when resizing of browser

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, responsive-design

I am converting a static page to a responsive page. My page a navigation bar which convert to a toggle navigation bar after 768 px.

i want to customize it my own at what width of bowser toggle navigation should come or not , initially i want it to come after 1024px but it is coming after 768px.

please help how i can do this. 
Please do not give downvote. it leads beginner like me to blocked by stackverflow.

Comment: share your code with the navigation toggle that appears after 768px

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: none !important;
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse.in {
        display: block !important;
    }
    .navbar-header .collapse, .navbar-toggle {
        display:block !important;
    }
    .navbar-header {
        float:none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  @media (min-width: 1024px) {
       /*toggle navigation class*/{
               width=/*whatever*/
             }
}
```

Comment: yeah, for example i wanna change my h1 size when i resize the screen.this h1 is in a div with "new" id name: @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    #new  h1{
        font-size:100%;
    } }

Comment: this will not work with my query . could you please provide me example of a toggle navigation bar in fiddle .

Comment: why don't you use bootstrap that helps you to resize the navigation bar with the size of the whole container with no problem

Comment: i am using boostarp. Boostarp allow toggle navigation just after 768px. i want it start it with 1024px. i have tried to put my code but bootstarp is blocking it

Comment: This is a code-only answer.  Please edit it to include a description of what this does, what it solves, and how it fits into the question.  Also, you'll never see an equals sign (`=`) in CSS.  I think you meant colon (`:`).  Rather than using comments, it would be more informative to use example values and then explain how to change them to other values in your description.